# Using lambdas and streams to create a purchase_items method

Tags: java, list, java-stream

The instructions say to create a method that accepts a retail_item object as an argument.  Each time the purchaseItem method is called, the retail_item that is passed as an argument should be added to the list.  I already have a list of the data in the store(list).  I need to create a new list that when the user selects an option from the store it creates a new list of purchased items.(Which will happen in a test class eventually)
 Below is what I have so far.  I know its not correct but having a lot of trouble with it.  Im new at this.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cash_Register object = new Cash_Register(); 
            developerInfo();

            Retail_item[] items = {
                    new Retail_item(1000, "Pants", 10, 19.99),
                    new Retail_item(2000, "Jeans", 2, 25.95),
                    new Retail_item(3000, "Shirt", 12, 12.50),
                    new Retail_item(4000, "Dress", 3, 79.00),
                    new Retail_item(5000, "Socks", 50, 1.98),
                    new Retail_item(6000, "Sweater", 5, 49.99),
                    new Retail_item(7000, "Jacket", 1, 85.95),
                    new Retail_item(8000, "Suit", 2, 150.98),
                    new Retail_item(9000, "Swimsuit", 6, 44.50),
                    new Retail_item(9500, "Skirt", 4, 65.99)};

            List<Retail_item> list = Arrays.asList(items);
            object.displayMenu(list);
            object.purchaseItem(list); 


}
//display menu
    public void displayMenu(List<Retail_item> list) {
        System.out.println("Menu Items: ");
        System.out.println("");
        list.stream()
            .forEach(System.out::println);

    }
    //create a purchased item list for register
    public void purchaseItem(List<Retail_item> list) {
        List<List<Retail_item>> toList = Arrays.asList(list);

        toList.stream()
                .map(Retail_item-> new Cash_Register())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());              

    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the line "user selects an option from the store" and what do you actually want.

Comment: We have a superclass that is the Retail_item that is all the setters and getters/toString method.  Then a second class Cash_Register that does all the functions of the cash register using superclass retail_item.  After that we are to create a test class or driver that will use the cash_register class and get user input and then print what is being purchased.   This is just one method of a very long and complicated assignment.   I tried just copying the instructions but it was to long.

Comment: @AmyHartmann: Please use the EDIT-Button to add this clarification to your question. Also reassure yourself that your code really illustrates your problem. If it doesn't, share code that illustrates it. If that code is too long, you should break down the problem in smaller problems, that you can illustrate with code of digestable length.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain why you need streams for this.  What your describing is this.

```
public void purchase_item( Retail_item item) {
        // the item list must exist somewhere, perhaps an instance field
        items.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are actually looking for, but with my guess hope this will be helpful. Please share what you want, what you have so far with details for the best answer.

```
    public class TestClass {

    List<Retail_item> retail_item_list = new ArrayList<Retail_item>();
    List<Retail_item> another_list = new ArrayList<Retail_item>();

    public void purchase_item(Retail_item retail_item) {

        retail_item_list.add(retail_item);

        Cash_Register cash_register = new Cash_Register();

        another_list = retail_item_list.stream()
            .map(item-> cash_register.method_name(item))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks like what im looking for.  I updated the code above with all that I have for this Class.

Comment: If you find your answer please ```accept the answer``` or ```upvote``` it

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that describes the problem you are having.